# Zip files according to date in filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I have the following requirement in windows batch file. I googled a lot but cannot find a definitive answer that suit my requirements.

I need to zip some files/folders based on date (file/folder names will contain this date). Date format is `YYYYY-MM-DD`. There are many group of files and only the date changes in them.

For example:

Group 1:
`ABCE2GDX2015-10-07ACCEQ`
`ABCE2GDX2015-10-06ACCEQ`
**`ABCE2GDX2015-10-05ACCEQ`

`ABCE2GDX2015-10-04ACCEQ`**

Group 2:
`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-10-0625`
`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-10-0425`
**`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-10-0225`

`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-09-3025`**

In my above example, I need to zip and then remove the files/folders except the top 2.

**`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-10-0225 -`** *should be placed in* `2015-10-02.zip`
**`HRCDGHHGGFGHJJHGGG2015-09-3025 -`** *should be placed in* `2015-09-30.zip`
**`ABCE2GDX2015-10-05ACCEQ        -`** *should be placed in* `2015-10-05.zip`
**`ABCE2GDX2015-10-04ACCEQ        -`** *should be placed in* `2015-10-04.zip`

Remaining files I should not touch.

How to achieve this? My current thinking is to

1. list `dir` contents to a file
2. take 1st line replace date part alone from the filename with `*`
3. list matched in 2nd file
4. remove matched lines in 1st file
5. zip as per date except first 2 lines from the 2nd file
6. and then go to 2nd line in first file and so on.

Problem I faced here is I don't know how to replace date alone with `*` and do a search in the file.

Please note PowerShell is not an option. I need to do it with either batch or VBScript or mix of both.

Comment: Instead of top 2, could be folder with a minimum age? Then `forfiles` or `robocopy` should do the trick.

Comment: Hard to find a pattern here without external regex tool

Comment: *Batch* is the wrong choice for this in my opinion (unless it is acceptable for you to use also third-party tools); the is only `findstr` that supports some kind of regular expression, but this has several issues and is poorly documented...

Answer (score 0):

In VBScript you could use a regular expression match on the filename.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})"

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\some\folder").Files
  For Each m In re.Execute(f.Name)
    zipfile = m.Submatches(0) & ".zip"
    'add file f to zipfile here
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Will this work for folders also? I mean if a folder contains date that i want , will the for each line pick that folder also and add to zip?

Comment: The sample code above processes files. If you want to process folders you need to replace `.Files` with `.SubFolders`.

Comment: But the above code did not account for zipping all the files in each group except top 2.